# early flush in gsp with grails

Tags: grails, gsp, flush

I'm trying to do early flush in gsp Grails 2.2.4 but not work.

```
<%
response.flushBuffer();
%>
```

and

```
<%

org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest webRequest =  (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest) org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()

webRequest.getOut().flush();

%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Early Flush

The responsible for not being able to manually flush the response is [GrailsPageFilter](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/bda7fde5eb748742616fcd1f4b5be9a880a9fff6/grails-web/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/sitemesh/GrailsPageFilter.java) filter, which wraps the response object so he can manage the response buffer.

You can skip this filter by creating a new filter in src/java:

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;

import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class BypassGrailsPageFilter implements Filter {

    private static final String ALREADY_APPLIED_KEY = "com.opensymphony.sitemesh.APPLIED_ONCE";

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {}

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest rq, ServletResponse rs, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) rq;

        req.setAttribute(ALREADY_APPLIED_KEY, Boolean.TRUE);

        chain.doFilter(req, rs);
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

And add it to your web.xml (located in src/templates/war), before sitemesh filter.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>nositemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.test.BypassGrailsPageFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>nositemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/path/to/controller/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Controller example:

```
class EarlyFlushController {

    def test() {
        def out = response.outputStream

        out << '<html>'
        out << '<body>'

        out.flush()

        (1..10).each { i ->
            out << i
            out.flush()
            Thread.sleep(1000)
        }

        out << '</body>'
        out << '</html>'
        out.flush()

        out.close()

        response.status = 200
    }
}
```

NOTE: If you cant find your web.xml try running `grails install-template` on your app dir.

---

### SiteMesh

You can still use grails templating system by using `g.render()` and sending its output to the response outstream.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense since you can by-pass sitemesh by using the instructions in http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5773 ( exclude sitemesh processing for certain urls by editing the web-app/WEB-INF/sitemesh.xml file).

Answer (score 0):

Sitemesh buffers the response for responses with text/html content type. You might have to exclude the uri from sitemesh. See http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5773 for details.

Comment: But I want use Sitemesh

Comment: Sitemesh buffers the request and then decorates it. You cannot use sitemesh with early flushing. There must be another way to solve your problem/use case.